# If folder exists based on string, copy files to existing folder

Tags: string, batch-file, if-statement, copy

I have a series of folders that I individually download via FTP on a daily basis.

Folder names are formatted as follows:

```
[DATE] [ID NO] [ID NAME]
```

Example:

```
W:\20150101 G0101 Building 1
W:\20150101 G0102 Building 2
W:\20150101 G0103 Building 3
```

[ID NO] and [ID NAME] are always the same. [DATE] changes each day.

I am trying to write a batch file to copy the contents of each FTP folder on a daily basis containing a known string to an equivalent local folder. Once the contents of each FTP folder are copied, the FTP folders are removed.

For example:

- Always copy the folder containing the string "G0101" on FTP drive "W:\" to "C:\Building 1"
- Always copy the folder containing the string "G0102" on FTP drive "W:\" to "C:\Building 2"

I have been playing around with IF EXIST but I can’t quite get the syntax right. Any assistance would be most appreciated!

```
IF EXIST "C:\00\*G0101*" XCOPY "C:\00\*G0101*\*.*" "C:\00\Building 1"
```

Regards

Martin :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only include a wildcard in the last element of the path. So, you need to enumerate the source folders and for each of them execute the xcopy operation

```
for /d %%a in ("c:\00\*G0101*") do xcopy "%%~fa\*.*" "c:\00\Building 1"
```

The `for /d` will search the folders matching the wildcard and for each of them a reference will be stored in the replaceable parameter `%%a` and the code in the `do` clause will be executed. `%%~fa` is just the reference to the folder with full path.

The code is written to be used inside a batch file. For usage in command line, replace all the double percent signs with single percent signs

Comment: Hello MC ND. Your response works perfectly. I am familiar with 'for do' but never thought of using it in this instance. Thankyou so much!